# Bash regex: What is ^()$ and what does it do?

Tags: bash, shell, regex

Recently, I was trying to find a nicer syntax to check one string against several possibilities. This led me to try

```
if [[ "hello" =~ "hi"|"hey"|"hello" ]]; then ...
```

Because it's a regex, it will trigger if the first string was something like `"NOThello"`. However, the following will match only the strings exactly, rejecting `"NOThello"`

```
if [[ "hello" =~ ^("hi"|"hey"|"hello")$ ]]; then ...
```

What is `^()$`? What does it do? Is it a feature of `[[`, or the shell?

I haven't been able to find anything on it in the man page and [other](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression) [resources](https://www.assertnotmagic.com/2018/06/20/bash-brackets-quick-reference/), my only reference is [this](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/246823-using-bash-regex-match-multiple-strings.html). The man page for `test` also doesn't have any information on this.

Bash version is `4.4.20`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex explanation:

```
^               # beginning of string
  (             # start capture group
    "hi"        # literally "hi"
   |           # OR
    "hey"       # literally "hey"
   |           # OR
    "hello"     # literally "hello"
  )             # end of group
$               # end of string
```

You will find usefull informations here:

- http://freecomputerbooks.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions.html
- https://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: D'oh, here I was thinking it was some subshell magic. Explains why nothing showed up, it was just regex logic. Thanks, accepted.